# Spring boot 1.5.8 with jakson 2.10.0 object mapping issue

Tags: spring-boot, fasterxml

i have upgraded jakson api on spring boot 1.5.8 from jakson 2.8.0 to 2.10.0, since then mapping of object is behaving different.

when i am passing request body on springboot controller having propertyname cityCode
sample json

```
{ 
cityCode:DEL
}
```

when adding jsonproperty mapping works fine

```
@JsonProperty("cityCode")
private String cityCode;
```

but when i don't add @JsonProperty annotation
it looks for CityCode instead.
since json passed on request is

```
{ 
cityCode:DEL
}
```

it assing

```
object{cityCode=null}
```

please let me know if there is any property which i need to add on spring boot

because in most of my scenario i don't want to add @JsonProperty annotation to class fields

EDIT:

I enable log.level to trace i saw some message related to jackson

POJOPropertyBuilder - Unable to instantiate jackson 2.6 object. Using higher version of jackson.

EDIT2:

Adding Sample Model Class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@ApiModel(value = "CityRequest")
public class CityRequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ApiModelProperty
    private String cityCode;

    @ApiModelProperty
    private String cityName;

    @ApiModelProperty
    private String area;

    @ApiModelProperty
    private List<String> areas;

    public String getCityCode() {
        return cityCode;
    }

    public void setCityCode(String cityCode) {
        this.cityCode = cityCode;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public List<String> getAreas() {
        return areas;
    }

    public void setAreas(List<String> areas) {
        this.areas = areas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CityRequest{" +
                "cityCode='" + cityCode + '\'' +
                ", cityName='" + cityName + '\'' +
                ", area='" + area + '\'' +
                ", areas=" + areas +
                '}';
    }
}
```

on the controller method is being passed as

```
@ApiParam(value = "This field specifies the list of requests", required = true) 
@Valid @RequestBody(required = true) CityRequest cityRequest
```

Comment: Do you have getter and setters for your POJO?

Comment: yes there is getter setter for POJO

Comment: Officially the version of Spring shipped with Spring Boot 1.5 doesn't support Jackson 2.10 or up, you would need a newer Spring version for that and thus a newer Spring BOot version (2.2 or up as Jackson 2.10 is supoprted there).

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, Thanks for suggestion, Will upgrading the spring boot to 2.2 fix the issue?

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, i have tried to upgrade spring boot to 2.2.6 still jackson mapping doesn't work.

Comment: Then there must be something weird in your dto that you aren't showing in your question here.

Comment: @M.Deinum, added the model class on question for reference

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but maybe you can try changing the naming strategy to lowerCamelCase:

```java
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.lowerCamelCase.class)
public class City {
    private String cityCode;
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for suggestion but there is no such PropertyNamingStrategy.lowerCamelCase.class we can directly use annotation @JsonNaming to use lower_camel_case strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give this a try as an app property to configure Jackson globally.

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=LOWER_CAMEL_CASE
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used one java api on spring-boot application where object mapper naming strategy is being set to upper_camel_case.

since that class imported on App.java(@SpringBootApplication) upper_camel_case strategy being applied globally.

to fix this globally imposed upper_camel_case strategy i have override the object mapper configuration on App.java and removed

```
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new UpperCamelCaseStrategy());
```

now i am able to use default naming strategy on application.